# Can I dynamically edit the output of my inventory when I print?

Tags: python, odoo, saas

I'm new to odoo and still exploring it, and I'm having a hard time on how can I approach this problem. Do I have the ability to change `print` action in odoo using their SaaS?

So for example, i have here a `pdf` result of transaction wherein it shows as a row

[image]

Can I customize it to be like this?

[image]

Or should I install the odoo to my pc and then manually customize the code there?

Thank you for the help, I'm still learning odoo

Comment: Depends on the report you want to customize. If you have admin access, you can do a lot of stuff, but you also can damage a lot of stuff ;-)